# "Love Above All"

Tags: word-meaning

I'm in Pimsleur's Italian 2, lesson 17 and they say something I can't figure out.

All I have is [the audio](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Bc236BlRlNTT9EhoGgmPuyR2vqRWmzu) (they don't supply transcripts), and it sounds to me like "L'amore non si tutto" and they say it means "Love above all", but that doesn't make sense to me -- in fact, it seem to me to mean the opposite: "Love is not everything"

I tried searching without success for this and various other phrases which sound the same to my ear, such as "L'amore nunsi tutto", "L'amore non situtto", "L'amore nonsi tutto" -- all of which I'm sure are laughable to an Italian reading this.  But that's where I'm at in my learning. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's Pimsleur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transcript of this audio is:

> – L'amore innanzitutto. 
>    – Love above all. 
>    – Eh, sì, l'amore innanzitutto.

They are using adverb  ["innanzitutto"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/innanzitutto), which means "prima di ogni altra cosa", that is, as you have said, "above all".

As mentioned by DaG in a comment and as you can see in [Sabatini Coletti dictionary](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/I/innanzitutto.shtml), it can also be written separately: "innanzi tutto".

Comment: Just mentioning that it's also possible to write it separately: _innanzi tutto_.

Comment: It makes so much sense now. Had never seen this adverb, and not sure I ever could have figured this out without help. Thanks for your help!